# How to compute $(i^2-i^4+i^6-i^8+...+i^{38})^2$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can i compute $(i^2-i^4+i^6-i^8+...+i^{38})^2$ ?

I can see that the powers are arithmetic progression with $d=2$ but i tried to compute

$S_{19}$ but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: what does $i$ means here? $i^2=-1$

Comment: You should notice that this is a geometric series such that $a_1=i^2 \ , \ q=-i^2 \ , \ n=19$. What is the sum of it?

Comment: yes, if you can see i tag it as complex numbers.

Comment: @Galc127 - so $S_{19}=\frac{i^2[(-i)^{38}-1]}{(-i)^2-1}$?

Comment: This is exact. Now what to you know about $\displaystyle i^{4n+k}$ where k such that $k\in[1,4]$? And do you see the problem?

Comment: $i^4 = i^8 = i^{12} = \ldots$ and $i^2 = i^6 = i^{10} = \ldots$..

Comment: @Galc127 - yes so how do i continue?

Comment: As simple as $(-19)^2$

Comment: @david, you should look on the given answers - using sum of geometric series doesn't work when $q=1$.

Comment: @Galc127: Are you sure? There seem to be $19$ times "$-1$" here...

Comment: @Galc127 why? as the Answer of Hagen it's really $(19i^2)^2$

Comment: You are right, I will delete my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $i^2=-i^4=i^6=-i^8=\ldots$ so that the sum simplifies *significantly*.

Answer (score 4):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Note that $i^{4n}-i^{4n+2}=2$  for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

So we know that $i^2$ = -1, and that squared is $i^4$ which is 1. As aforementioned, $i^2 = -i^4$. Because, $i^4=1$, $i^2=i^6=i^{10}...i^{38}$, and $i^4=i^8..i^{36}$. Therefore, canceling out terms leaves us with $(i^{38})^2$, which evaluates to $(-1)^2$, which we know to be one.

==> $(((i^2-i^4)+(i^6-i^8)...(i^{34}-i^{36})+i^{38})^2$ = $(0+0+0+..+(-1))^2$ = (-1)^2 = 1